# Looking for the OPLS parameters for octanol

Tags: molecular-dynamics, gromacs

I have been looking for OPLS gromacs parameters for 1-octanol, but haven't been able to get it. Doing a quick web search takes me into links for lipidbook, from which I can't download at all from https://lipidbook.org/lipid/show/id/10.html . Can someone please advise, or show me right direction? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "I have not been able to get it." ?
Also please add relevant links. Also please add details on what exactly you have already done.

Comment: I have added the relevant links

Comment: The download seems to be empty. However, you can try this [link](http://zarbi.chem.yale.edu/ligpargen/index.html) to generate the parameters

Answer (score 2):

I have opened a GitHub repository which you can find at https://github.com/roshan2004/OPLS_AA_solvents, where I will try to upload OPLS/AA gromacs parameters for the available solvents in the coming days. I have uploaded the OPLS/AA gromacs parameters for 1-octanol.